# $L^1$ equicontinuity for functions with uniformly bounded total variation

Tags: lebesgue-integral, compactness, lp-spaces, bounded-variation

I've been trying to prove that the space $BV[0, 1]$ of elements of $L^1 [0, 1]$ with bounded variation, is compactly embedded in $L^1[0, 1]$, using the [Fréchet-Kolmogorov theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_theorem#Statement).

For context, a *function* $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb C$ is said to have bounded variation if its total variation, defined by
$$
V_0^1 (f) = \sup_P \sum_{j = 1}^n |f(x_j) - f(x_{j-1})|
$$
is finite (where the supremum I taken over the set of partitions $P = \{ x_0, x_1, ..., x_n \}$ with $0 = x_0 < x_1 < ... < x_n = 1$). If $f$ is instead an *equivalence class* of functions equal a.e. (e.g., an element of $L^1$), $f$ is said to be of bounded variation if it has a version that has bounded variation, and we set $V_0^1 (f) = \inf\{ V_0^1(g) : g \in f \}$.

The space $BV[0, 1]$ is endowed with the norm $\|f\|_{BV} = \|f\|_1 + V_0^1(f)$. To prove that the embedding $BV \hookrightarrow L^1$ is compact, it suffices to show that $B = \{ f \in BV[0, 1] : \|f\|_{BV} \le 1 \}$ is relatively compact in $L^1$.

Since we're working over $[0, 1]$ which is a bounded subset of $\mathbb R$, we have equitightness of $B$. All that remains to check is the equicontinuity property:
$$
\| \tau_h f - f \|_1 \underset{h \to 0}{\longrightarrow} 0, \text{ uniformly for } f\in B
$$
where $\tau_h f (x) = f(x + h)$.

**Note:** functions defined on $[0, 1]$ are extended as usual by the value $0$ outside of $[0, 1]$.

**My attempt:** let $\epsilon > 0$ and consider a version $g_\epsilon$ of $f \in B$ s.t. $V_0^1(g_\epsilon) \le V_0^1(f) + \epsilon$ (such a $g_\epsilon$ exists by definition of the infimum).

I tried using the inequality
$$
 |g_\epsilon (a) - g_\epsilon (b)| \le V_a^b (g_\epsilon) \label{1}\tag{$*$}
$$ with $0\le a\le b \le 1$, in the hope of being able to use the condition that $\|f\|_{BV} \le 1$ to get something in the likes of $\| \tau_h f - f \|_1 \le \epsilon + R(h)$, where $R(h)$ would be something independent of $f$ and $R(h) \underset{h \to 0}{\longrightarrow} 0$. However, I am unsure how to proceed from \eqref{1} to obtain such an inequality. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: I know a proof but it is using the fact that for smooth functions the variation is the integral of the derivative and mollifiers. Do you know these results?

Comment: @Gio67 I do know that if $f$ is $C^1$ then $V_0^1(f) = \int_0^1 |f'|$. I'm interested to see how mollifiers come into play though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\delta>0$ be small and take $0<\varepsilon<\delta$. If you play with the fundamental theorem of calculus you should get
$$\int_0^{1-\delta}|f_\varepsilon(x+h)-f_\varepsilon(x)|dx\le h\int_0^1|f’_\varepsilon(x)|\, dx=h V^1_0(f_\varepsilon).$$
Then you use the fact that the variation of the mollifiers is less than the variation of the function (see [variation of mollifier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4246296/mollification-of-functions-of-bounded-variation)) so you get$$\int_0^{1-\delta}|f_\varepsilon(x+h)-f_\varepsilon(x)|dx\le h V^1_0(f).$$
Then you let $\varepsilon $ goes to zero and use Fatous’s lemma on the left hand side.
To use mollifiers, you should probably extend your function    a bit outside $(0,1)$, that is define $f(x)=f(1)$ for $x>1$ and $f(x)=f(0)$ for $x<0$. I am skipping a lot of details.

Then you have $$\int_{1-\delta}^1|f(x+h)-f(x)|\, dx\le 2\delta\sup|f|.$$
I guess you could take $\delta=h$.

**EDIT**
A simpler proof that does not use mollifiers.
Extend $f$ to be $f(1)$ for $x\geq1$. Let $m=\lfloor1/h\rfloor$, so that
$mh\leq1\leq(m+1)h$. By the change of variables $x=kh+y$,
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}|f(x+h)-f(x)|\,dx  & \leq\sum_{k=0}^{m}\int_{kh}^{(k+1)h}%
|f(x+h)-f(x)|\,dx\\
& =\sum_{k=0}^{m}\int_{kh}^{(k+1)h}|f(x+h)-f(x)|\,dx\\
& =\int_{0}^{h}\sum_{k=0}^{m}|f((k+1)h+y)-f(kh+y)|\,dy\\
& \leq h\operatorname*{Var}f
\end{align*}

Comment: My attempt for the first part:
$\int_0^1 |f_\epsilon (x + h) - f_\epsilon(x)| \, dx \le \int_0^1 \int_x^{x+h} |{f_\epsilon'(t)}| \, dt \, dx = \int_0^h \int_0^1 |{f_\epsilon'(x + t)}| \, dx \, dt$
I'm stuck at the last one, I'd like to use invariance of the $L^1$ norm by translation, which would work on $\mathbb R$ but not necessarily on $[0, 1]$...

Comment: Yes, I think you need to restrict the domain. I edited it. See if it works now.

Comment: If you take $h$ to be positive, this does seem to work for $\delta = h$ (for $h$ negative, set instead $\delta =-h$). Now to find a bound for the remaining term $\int_{1-h}^1 |\tau_h f - f|$ that does not depend on $f$:
$$|f(x)| = \int_0^1 |f(x)| dy \le \int_0^1 (|f(y)|+|f(x)-f(y)|)dy \le \int_0^1 |f| + V_0^1 (f)$$
which for $f \in B$ is going to be $\le1$. I think it works now, thanks!